# Client comm layer received more data from the Advantage Database Server than it was expecting

Tags: join, advantage-database-server

I'm pulling data from our Advantage Database Server via an ODBC SQL connection in Power Query. Everything was working fine, there a few joins bringing additional data. All good.

I then add one additional joined field, and get the message:

`DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL][ASA] Error 6605:  Client comm layer received more data from the Advantage Database Server than it was expecting.  axOpenTable`

any idea what it means? thanks.

edit: I do the same join and lookup in another table, using the same logic. So it should in theory work.

Answer (score 0):

The 66xx errors are communication error between server and client, i.e. problem with ADS:

https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage12/index.html?error_advantage_66xx_error_codes.htm

It will require the SAP/Sybase to research and fix the problem. However, it appears that the Advantage Database Product is no longer in active development so you are unlikely to get any help from them. Might as well to just re-write query to see if you can work around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i have found some solution on internet:

*Problem Description:
An Advantage enabled application is returning the error 6605
(Client comm layer received more data from the Advantage Database Server than it was expecting).

Solution:
In a few cases it has been found that network packets were being fragmented as they were sent to and returned from the Advantage server.

It may be possible to mask the packet fragmentation by reducing the packet size used when communicating between the Advantage client and
Advantage server and work around this problem. However this should only be used as a short term solution and further investigation into
why packets are being fragmented is recommended.

To reduce the packet size used during network communication for Advantage, add the following line to the [SETTINGS] section of the ads.ini.
The default and maximum value is 1450 for IP. If this works, you may choose to slowly increase the packet size to maximize the value before
the error returns as a smaller packet size may cause reduced application performance.

PACKET_SIZE=512*